# JavaFX TextField listener is never called

Tags: javafx, textview, listener

I have a simple dialog with some text fields and I want to add a simple listener to a property of the TextField. Should be a no brainer, but it's never called it seems. Debugging reveals that the listener is added (I think), but it doesn't do anything. My feeling is that it gets garbage collected. Question is, why?

ps. Adding a setOnKeyPressed handler does work fine, as do all other operations on it.

This is my class:

```
public class MyClass {
    @FXML
    private TextField emailTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField codeTextField;
    @FXML
    private TextField nameTextField;

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StageController.class.getName());

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        emailTextField.onKeyPressedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            LOG.info("Hi!");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding a `ChangeListener` to the `onKeyPressed` property. This property is itself an event handler which responds to key presses, and your code means that whenever the `onKeyPressed` property changes, i.e. any time `setOnKeyPressed(...)` or `onKeyPressedProperty().set(...)` is called, your listener is invoked.

So your listener is never invoked because the `onKeyPressedProperty()` never changes.

You probably don't want to respond to changes in the `onKeyPressedProperty()`, but instead (perhaps) want to actually respond to key presses. You do this by either setting the `onKeyPressed` property, or adding another event handler.

Either:

```
emailTextField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> LOG.info("Hi!"));
```

or:

```
emailTextField.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> LOG.info("Hi!"));
```

Even this is likely not what you want. The text field already knows what to do when a key is pressed; depending on the key it may change the text. What you more typically want to do is respond to the text changing:

```
emailTextField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> LOG.info(newText));
```

This will respond to text changes, whether or not they occur due to key presses (e.g. it will respond to the user pasting text with the mouse) but will not respond to key presses that don't change anything (e.g. pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, or <kbd>DELETE</kbd> when the text field is empty).

Comment: Ahhh, that was the key, I knew it must have been an oversight for something so basic. :) That property is by itself a listener, I wouldn't have guessed that. Indeed adding a listener to the textProperty works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @supernov The [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#onKeyPressedProperty) tells you what a property contains. `onKeyPressedProperty()` is an `ObjectProperty<EventHandler<KeyEvent>>`, so it contains an `EventHandler<KeyEvent>`.

Comment: Yes, a case of rtfm indeed. I managed to not encounter this specific case yet it seems, thanks for the explanation!